# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [645471, 78]

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

How can I fix this error it throws? ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [645471, 78]

full code attached

```
#Importing the numpy to perform Linear Algebraic operations on the data
import numpy as np
#Import pandas library to perform the data preprocessing
import pandas
#importing the Keras deep learning framework of Python
import keras
#Importing the Sequential model from keras
from keras.models import Sequential
#Importing the types of layers in the Neural Network that we are going to have
from keras.layers import Dense
#Importing the train_test_split function which is useful in dividing the dataset into the training and testing data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#Importing the StandardScaler function to perform the standardisation/scaling of the data
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder
#Importing the metries for the performance evaluation of our deep learning model
from sklearn import metrics
from keras.utils import np_utils, normalize, to_categorical

data = pandas.read_csv("C:/Users/bam/train.csv", header=0, dtype=object)
X = data.iloc[:, 0:78]
y = data.iloc[:78]
#I have splitted the dataset into a ratio of 80:20 between the train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 23)
#Creating an object of StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
#Scaling the data using the StandardScaler() object
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrX4p.png)

Comment: Can you change the assignment to y as `y = data.iloc[:,78]`. I think there is a mismatch in size there

Comment: Yeah you are just indexing your dataframe in the wrong way, producing variables with different number of samples